# How do i clear testing entries in all forms in openerp 7 before final deployment?

Tags: testing, configuration, odoo

After setting up the openerp system, How do i clear testing entries in all forms in openerp 7 before final deployment? Or Is there a seperate testing methodology to test openerp 7. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can use yaml testing or unittest2 python package for testing in openerp.

http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/05_test_framework/

http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/how-effective-yaml-testing-openerp